# How to keep javascript applet on page change?

Tags: javascript, html, persistence

How to keep javascript code running (or rerun it but keep state) when user navigates away from web page?

Only using of frames coming to my mind.

Are there any more ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep it running, but I seriously recommend **[Amplify.JS's Store API](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/)**.

It let's you save data using key/value pairs by abstracting a number of browser storage features that may be available.

**Update:** [Example usage](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.5/appendto/amplify/tree/master/store/demo/implicit/).

It's very simple:

```
amplify.store("foo", "bar");
```

Stores value `"bar"` on key `"foo"`. You can access/modify this in another page. `"bar"` can also be an object, anything you can think of! It can be numbers or a whole complex object full of nodes.

```
foobar = amplify.store("foo");
```

Retrieves the mixed value (`"bar"`, or anything you think of, such as `[1,2,3,4]`) stored on `"foo"`.

If still having trouble, why not [***debug it***](http://getfirebug.com/)? Then you can tell (us) where's the error(s).

Comment: If I have JS in remaining frame, why won't it run?

Comment: What do you mean? it does run, even in a frame. I'll update an example.